# Are These Right Metaphors?

Tags: metaphors

> Metaphor :  "My Computer Is A Headache".
>   Meaning : My computer gives late response.
>
> Metaphor : "This Car Is, Pain In Ass".
>   Meaning : This car keeps getting out of order again & again.
>
> Metaphor : "My Friend Is A Lion".
>   Meaning : My friend is brave.
>
> Metaphor : "He Is An Elephant"
>   Meaning : He is fat.
>
> Metaphor : "Your Dog Is A Ghost"
>   Meaning : Your dog is horrible.
>
> Metaphor : "These People Are Dragons".
>   Meaning : These people are very angry.

Are they right ? If not, then please tell me where I'm wrong.

Comment: A metaphor is supposed to convey something via an analogy. What are you trying to say with these statements? Anyhow, the last four seem like metaphors to me, but I'm not sure about the first two.

Comment: What do you mean by "right"? If a metaphoric usage genuinely expresses what you want to say, no-one else can say it's "wrong". Even if your metaphoric reference is so unusual they've no idea what you actually mean. *My friend is a bicycle*, for example, would be incomprehensible to most people unless they'd heard a joke along the lines of *...been ridden by everyone*.

Comment: ...bear in mind that because of *cultural* differences, a lot of metaphors that might seem perfectly natural in your own language won't work very well in English. So if you want to sound like a native speaker (rather than a wannabee poet), avoid creating new metaphoric usages - stick to the ones you hear in English, and don't worry about them being called cliches.

Comment: If you specifically wanted to convey that your computer "gives a late response" (not natural English in this context, but I assume you mean the computer is *slow*), the ***headache*** metaphor wouldn't do that. Usually when we say something is a headache, we mean it's *troublesome*, not "slow to respond". To repeat the advice; avoid making up your own metaphors.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And what if i meant " My computer is defective so that i need to repair it again & again " ??

Comment: @Ahtisham: You could perhaps say *My computer is an old [jalopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decrepit_car)* (a car that is often old and damaged and is in a barely functional state, so would be likely to need constant repair). But this is all a matter of "creative writing", not particularly useful to those who aren't familiar with the vocabulary, standard cliches, and cultural stereotypes of the people who use the relevant language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you some observations on typical usage of the metaphors you describe.

1. As FumbleFingers mentions, something is a *headache* when it is troublesome.  There isn't a common metaphor that conveys the idea of slowness, but we often say *slow as molasses.*
2. *Pain in the ass* is considered vulgar (though in regular usage, my mother, for example, would never dream of using it).  *Pain in the neck* is more polite.  Both have the meaning of troublesome, similar to *headache*.  If a mechanical device breaks down a lot we might refer to it as a *bucket of bolts.*
3. We also use the metaphor of *lion* to mean brave, although it isn't particularly common.
4. We generally use *hippopotamus* (more often *hippo*) to suggest that someone is fat.  This is considered a strong insult, and is more typically said of women than men.  A man would be more often referred to as a *tub of lard*.  Again, this would be highly insulting.  *Elephants* are more associated with good memory in English; we might say that someone has *a memory like an elephant* (we might even say that someone is an elephant, if the meaning of having a good memory were clear from context).
5. *Your dog is a ghost* doesn't have the meaning you describe at all in English.  It could only be interpreted as a rather strange way of telling someone that their dog is dead.  More typical would be *your dog is a monster*.
6. To call someone a *dragon* is to say they are bad-tempered and is an insult (although not as much of an insult as calling them a hippopotamus).  This is typically said of women rather than men (if you called a man a dragon, you would probably be saying that he is a good fighter); we use the term *dragon lady* as well.

Comment: And you as well.  :)  I think you are doing just fine, except your computer is a pain in *the* neck, and these ladies are *dragons* or this lady is *a dragon*.  Again, calling someone a tub of lard is insulting.

Comment: 's    1) My computer is a pain in neck. 2) My car is a bucket of bolts. 3) My Friend Is a lion 4) He is a tub of lard. 5) Your dog is a monster. 6) These ladies are dragon. what you think now ? :D

Comment: @AhtishamChishti 6 still sounds strange to me.